# Application Version INSTANT_RUN?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

So, yay, instant run provides a semi-"instant" build (Well... 7 seconds is not "instant" but whatever).

---

Now, I know everything comes with pros and cons, but I can't seem to fix this bug that my Android App's version is "`INSTANT_RUN`". Here's my gradle line:

```
versionName "0.1 Beta"
```

I tried removing `beta` but apparently it's not the problem.

---

Although I'm much of a thug life person, I searched SO and I found a question, and the answer to it was downgrading Gradle Build Tools, which won't help me since I need the latest version to prevent bugs.

I've looked everywhere in Android Studio, but didn't find anything.

Comment: What if not use Instant Run? it's _really_ unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't posted if your gradle has a versionCode line, like this

```
versionCode 1
```

if it doesn't have that line, try adding it..

if it still doesn't work, try disabling instant run.